# Wordpress theme imported demo not working correctly

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I uploaded a purchased theme in Wordpress, but the imported demo I wish to use as my starting point isn't displaying corrrectly and I can't figure out what I need to do to fix this issue.

The theme came in a zip file that contained the main theme, child, licensing, plugins, data_exports, and Documentation. I followed the documentation, as well as a video guide provided on the theme's site. I wasn't able to upload the enitre zip file, so I uploaded the main theme and child. I then installed all of the plugins that came with the upload of the main theme. After that, I went into the "Demo Importer" and imported the demo that I wished to use as my starting point.

[Here is what is being displayed currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZOCG.png)

I am also getting a few plugins that say they need updated, but when I attempt to updated them I am getting errors:

[Here is a screnshot of the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVNah.png)

After reading through the documentation provided, I am still unable to fix the issue. I don't know if this is a plugin issue, or user error. I am sure this is just a begginers mistake, but I am hoping to find a solution through much more experienced devs.

Comment: EDIT: I found the solution and decided to leave the post up in case someone else ran into the same problem. The issue was that duplicate demo content was imported due to accidentally clicking the ‘Import’ button multiple times.  That made it so elements and settings were displayed from both imported demos, which could break the layout and the design. Sometimes, importing a demo can take a few minutes so make sure to be patient. This is a link to remove content and start over.

https://www.themezwp.com/demo-import/how-to-remove-duplicate-demo-content-after-import/